# Subcribe websocket from Rails 5.1 Vue.js webpack

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I have a Vue.js template inside Rails 5.1 app with latest webpack and calling REST API publicClient.getProducts() methods works fine. But subscribing a websocket connection is getting a problem as shown below.

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://ws-feed.gdax.com/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)."

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/nengine/e216c080988fca7cf4c3aa26f388f236

Answer (score 1):

The error message reveals that your API server is located in a different domain (https://ws-feed.gdax.com/) than the domain (not specified in the question) that served your frontend code vue.js. The browser will prevent such requests as a [security mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

The server has to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [frontend domain]` headers to allow for [cross origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

There are [rails plugins](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) that can be configured to do just that.

Comment: Rails 5.1 vue.js client app is on the localhost for development.  I was told  from gdax dev team that embedding gdax client into web pages would not be supported for now, so I would need to proxy all requests.  No so sure what that means, but I don't have problem opening websockets from express.js server side app.  Thank you.